# How to get the erased type of a type parameter inside a class

Tags: class, kotlin, generics, type-erasure

I know that, during runtime type parameters will be erased and hence we cannot access it directly. That's why there are reified type parameters in kotlin. But its usage is restricted only for functions. I even tried receiving explicit argument in constructor like this:

```
class Outer<T> {
    inner class Inner(private val clazz: Class<T>) {
        private fun func() {
            if (obj is clazz) {    // even tried obj is clazz::class.java
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me `Unresolved reference: clazz` error in android studio. Someone please help me.

Comment: "even tried obj is clazz::class.java" That would be the class object of `java.lang.Class` so it's good it didn't succeed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clazz` is not a class name, so you can't use `is` with it. It is a property with a type of `Class<T>`. So you have to use `==` to compare with it.

```
if (obj::class.java == clazz) { // ...
```

Comment: Note `obj::class.java == clazz` is false is `obj` is actually an instance of a subclass, while `is` would be true. To include subclasses, go with gidds' answer. (I am sure you know this, but people who read the answer may not!).

Comment: You can compare Class objects taking subclasses into account, by using [Class.isAssignableFrom()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-).  (But I think [Class.isInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) is simpler and clearer in this case.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the dynamic equivalent of `is`, which is [`Class.isInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-):

```
if (clazz.isInstance(obj)) { // ...
```

(KClass has an [`isInstance()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/is-instance.html) method too, if you want to stick to pure Kotlin.)